# C Programming in OPNET

Tags: c++, c, packet, indirection

I'm starting some work into manual programming of nodes in OPNET however I am having a few troubles. I'm getting some information from packets and storing them in variables and want to output this to the simulation console. When I add the line puts(bcast_info) I get the following error.

```
C:/Users/Andrew/op_models/traffic_source.pr.c(74) : warning C4047:
'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from
'Objid' C:/Users/Andrew/op_models/traffic_source.pr.c(74) : warning
C4024: 'puts' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

Prior to adding the line mentioned above, the simulation worked perfectly and I got the basic text output. This is my code so far.

```
 static void route_pk(void)
    {
    Packet * pkptr;
    Objid bcast_info;
    FIN(route_pk());
    pkptr = op_pk_get(op_intrpt_strm ());
    bcast_info = op_pk_bcast_get (pkptr);
    printf ("Hello! \n");
    puts("Hello from puts");
    puts(bcast_info);
    op_pk_send (pkptr, 1);
    FOUT;
    }
```

I appreciate that OPNET is a variation on the C language with some of its own methods etc but any help on what the errors actually mean and potential fixes would be much appreciated. Please be aware that I have never worked with C / C++ or this OPNET language before.

Comment: What is `Objid`? Debug your program until you have a minimal testcase.

Comment: puts expects a const char *. Instead you supply an Objid. We dont know what one of those is

Comment: Well according to OPNET its an object identifier to return the ID of a specified object. According to their database of documentation "
numeric object ID or hierarchical name of the object-of-interest" and the following example is given. objid pksw2.node0
 object ID:  9

Comment: As for the language, I don't know. Its a hybrid of C and C++ according to the help files

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the `print()` function. Use the `op_prg_odb_print_major()` function.

`Objid` is a special data type in Modeler. You can't print it to screen.